# Handling Pk[Int] values in spray-json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

**[edit]**

So, i got a quick and dirty solution, thanks to `Edmondo1984`, I don't know if it's the best solution.  I don't handle null values with pattern matching at the write function. You can read more details about my problem after this editing. Here is my code now:

```
object DBNames extends DefaultJsonProtocol {



  implicit val pkFormat: JsonFormat[Pk[Int]] = new JsonFormat[Pk[Int]] {

    def write(obj: Pk[Int]): JsValue = JsNumber(obj.get)

    def read(json: JsValue): Pk[Int] = json.asJsObject.getFields("id") match {
      case Seq(JsNumber(id)) => new Pk[Int] { id.toInt }
      case _ => throw new DeserializationException("Int expected")
    }
  }

  implicit val nameFormat = jsonFormat2(Name)
```

jsonFormat2 will implicitly use pkFormat to parse Pk[Int] values.

In my controller class I have this:

```
def listNames() = Action {
    val names = DBNames.findAll()
    implicit val writer = DBNames.nameFormat
    var json = names.toJson

    Ok(json.toString()).as("application/json")
```

}

I had to get the `nameFormat` from my model and make it implicit, so `bars.toJson` could use it to parse the `Seq[Name]` names.

**[/edit]**

I'm trying to use Play! Framework with Scala, I'm new to Scala programming and Play Framework, and everything seems nice, but I'm working on this problem during several hours and didn't find a solution.

I have a Case Class:

```
case class Name (id: Pk[Int], name: String)
```

And an object to deal with MySql. I created a `implicit val nameFormat = jsonFormat2(Name)` to deal with JSON.

```
object DBNames extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit val nameFormat = jsonFormat2(Name)

  var parser =
  {
    get[Pk[Int]]("id") ~
    get[String]("name")  map {
      case id ~ name =>  Name(id,name)
    }
  }

  def findAll():Seq[Name] =
  {
     DB.withConnection {
       implicit connection =>
         SQL("select * from names").as(DBNames.parser *)
     }

  }

  def create(name: Name){
    DB.withConnection {
      implicit connection =>
        SQL("insert into names (name) values ({name})").on(
          'name -> name.name
        ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }


}
```

But when I try to compile it, Play! gives me this result:

```
[error] D:\ProjetosJVM\TaskList\app\models\Names.scala:20: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type models.DBNames.JF[anorm.Pk[Int]]
```

It seems like he couldn't find a way to parse the `id` value, since it is a Pk[Int] value.

So, by reading this: `https://github.com/spray/spray-json` I didn't found a way to parse it without creating a complete object parser like they show in the documentation:

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object ColorJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Color] {
    def write(c: Color) = JsObject(
      "name" -> JsString(c.name),
      "red" -> JsNumber(c.red),
      "green" -> JsNumber(c.green),
      "blue" -> JsNumber(c.blue)
    )
    def read(value: JsValue) = {
      value.asJsObject.getFields("name", "red", "green", "blue") match {
        case Seq(JsString(name), JsNumber(red), JsNumber(green), JsNumber(blue)) =>
          new Color(name, red.toInt, green.toInt, blue.toInt)
        case _ => throw new DeserializationException("Color expected")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a "big" (actually small) project where I want to make most of things work with Ajax, so I think this is not a good way to do it.

How can I deal with JSON objects in this project, where almost all `case classes` will have a "JSON parser", without creating large ammounts of code, like the snippet above? And also, how can I make it work with an `Seq[Name]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write a complete parser. The compiler says:

```
[error] D:\ProjetosJVM\TaskList\app\models\Names.scala:20: could not find implicit 

value for evidence parameter of type models.DBNames.JF[anorm.Pk[Int]]
```

The scala compiler is looking for an **implicit parameter** of type `JF[anorm.Pk[Int]]` and there is no such an implicit parameter in scope. What is `JF[anorm.Pk[Int]]`? Well, you need to know the library and I didn't, so I had browsed `spray-json` source and found out:

```
trait StandardFormats {
  this: AdditionalFormats =>

  private[json] type JF[T] = JsonFormat[T] // simple alias for reduced verbosity
```

so `JF[T]` is just an alias for `JsonFormat[T]`. It all make sense: `PK[Int]` is a class coming from `Anorm` and `spray-json` provides out-of-the-box json support for standard types, but does not even know `Anorm` exists So you have to code your support for `Pk[Int]` and make it implicit in scope.

You will have code like the following:

```
object DBNames extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

   implicit val pkFormat : JsonFormat[Pk[Int]] = new JsonFormat[Pk[Int]] {
      //implementation
   }
   // rest of your code
}
```

If you have just started with Scala, you would probably have to read more about implicits and their resolution. I am providing you with a minimal answer: once you have provided the right implementation, your code will compile. I suggest you to refer to the javadoc of anorm.Pk and of JsonFormat to understand how to implement it correctly for your type.

`Pk` looks like `scala.Option` and in `StandardFormats` source code inside spray-json you find the `JsonFormat` implementation for Option, from which you can copy

Comment: Thanks, Edmondo. I truly have to read more about implicits, they work like magic. If a variable is not supplied but can be taken from the implicits in the scope, they will be used. Thats what they are looking like. `jsonFormat2` doesn't know how to parse a `Pk[Int]`, but he knows that there is a value called `pkFormat` who knows how to, so he will use it.